# How to use Solr's CurrencyField and avoid "missing required field" error

Tags: solr

I am trying to use Solr's CurrencyField. I am using the example Solr instance (apache-solr-4.0.0/example/solr/collection1) to test the CurrencyField. I have added a field to the schema.xml as follows:

```
<field name="money" type="currency" indexed="true" stored="false" required="true" multiValued="false" />
```

However, when posting the XML file:

```
<doc>
    <field name="id">12344321</field>
    <field name="text">4312341</field>
    <field name="money">1.30,USD</field>
</doc>
```

I get the following error:

```
SEVERE: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: [doc=4312341] missing required field: money
```

Why am I getting this error, and how can I fix it?

I am using Solr 4.0.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Paige is correct: You are getting this error because CurrencyField is a PolyField.

The following document shows *three* fields: the field "money", and two special dynamic fields "__raw_amount" and "__currency".

```
<doc>
    <field name="money">1.30,USD</field>
</doc>
```

A workaround to keeping the "money" field not stored is to include it as a dynamic field.

```
<dynamicField name="*_c" type="currency" indexed="true" stored="false" />
```

My guess is that Solr dynamically generates new stored fields for both the raw amount and the currency.

That said, this question is a great candidate for the mailing list.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of trial and error, I discovered a solution: the money field must have stored="true" in the schema.xml.

```
<field name="money" type="currency" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
```

I do not know *why* this works.

Comment: Might have something to do with the fact that CurrencyField is a Poly Field Type - http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#Poly_Field_Types that get potentially splits values into multiple fields per field declaration.